# Mongoose MongoDB | Adding data to existing documents' objects in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the module Mongoose for MongoDB. Everytime the user submits data to my node server, it is processed something like this:

```
var personSchema = mongoose.Schema({ //a new schema
properties: {}, //dynamic properties
keys: [],
houses:[],
family:[]
}, {strict: false});

var NewPerson = mongoose.model('people', personSchema);//

var personObject = {properties: {
    keys: ['data that was pushed previously'];
    houses: ['data that was pushed previously'];
    family: ['data that was pushed previously'];
}}


var person = NewPerson(personObject, false);    

person.save(function(err){
if(err){
    console.log('database error');
    throw err;
} 
    console.log('cropped document saved.'); 
});
```

Now until this point, all is well; problem is, that in the future my users would want to make edits/add new data such as new houses/family etc, how do I do it?
I mean, I already coded a form submission which sends their mongodb id, with that id I want to access the document they saved inside my people collection(I know how to access a document using the function findOne), and then push their new form data to keys, houses, family arrays and finally save it  in the database. 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

or you can just use `update()` method，this approach can modify the data in the mongodb, you do not need find it, change it and save it.

Comment: Actually finding it, modifying it and then saving it may lead to unexpected results when multiple users access the same database. Using update is the only proper way to do it in Mongo.